# After accepting data with @requestbody, I want to return message or realize webpage-jump

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="receive", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public  RegInfo receiveData(@RequestBody RegInfo info){
    String reg_check = regInfoService.checkRegInfo(info);     
     ......
}
```

RegInfo:

```
public class RegInfo {

private String account;

private String passwords;

private String realname;

private String phonenumber;

private String sex;

private String mailname;
.......}
```

register.jsp:

```
    $("#sub").click(function(){
    var m = {
            "account": $("#_account").val(),
            "passwords": $("#_pass").val(),
            "realname": $("#real_name").val(),
            "phonenumber": $("#phone_number").val(),
            "sex": $("input:checked").val(),
            "mailname": $("#mail_name").val()
        };
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        async : false,
        url:"/demo/user/receive",
        dataType:"json",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data:JSON.stringify(m),
        success:function(data){
            alert("ok");
            alert(data.realname);
        },
        erroe:function(data){
            alert("保存失败 ")
        }
    })
});
```

Now I want to check RegInfo in the controller. If the result of check is legal, I want to jump to other webpage like `login.jsp` and if it is illegal, I want to return some message and show the message in `register.jsp`. How can I realize it?
complete Controller：

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;    
    @Autowired
    private RegInfoService regInfoService;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String homePage(){
        return "user/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/loginin")
    public String toLogin(@ModelAttribute("user")User user){
        String u = userService.loginCheck(user);
        System.out.println(u);
        if(u == "success"){
            return "user/success";
        }
        else{
            return "user/login";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/register")
    public String toRegister(){
        return "user/register";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/success")
    public String toSuccess(){
        return "user/success";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="receive", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public RegInfo receiveData(@RequestBody RegInfo info){

        String reg_check = regInfoService.checkRegInfo(info);
        System.out.println(reg_check);
        System.out.println(info);
        System.out.println(info.getRealname());
        return info;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test as follows:

```
<input type="button" value="test" onClick="newpage()">
function newpage(){
window.location="/demo/user/login";}
```

then it jump to login.jsp successfully.In the ajax,it had run to "window.location" but didn't jump.It looks so strange.

Final solution：
error：

```
<input type="submit" id="sub" value="save" >
```

true：

```
<input type="button" id="sub" value="save" >
```

Form is submitted twice.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to jump to other webpage like login.jsp and if it is illegal, I
>   want to return some message and show the message in register.jsp. How
>   can I realize it?

Simple, in your AJAX success handler redirect with URL parameters like:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        async : false,
        url:"/demo/user/receive",
        dataType:"json",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data:JSON.stringify(m),
        success:function(data){
            alert("ok");
            alert(data.realname);
            if (data.realname != undefined || data.realname!= null) {
              window.location = '/login?realname=' + data.realname;
            }
        },
        erroe:function(data){
            alert("保存失败 ")
        }
    });
```

EDITS:
based on your comment the controller method will look like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String homePage(Mode model, @RequestParam(value="realname",required=false)String realName){
        if(realName!=null && (!realName.trim().isEmpty())){
           model.addAttribute("regSuccessUser",realName);
        }
        return "user/login";
    }
}
```

and redirect statement will look like:

```
window.location = '/user/login?realname=' + data.realname;
```

<sub>Note: URL start with contextPath to avoid 404 problems</sub>

Comment: I edit as you say but it still does not jump to the new page.It can run into if{} but does not do effect.

Comment: @TX2012LH can you show your controller request mapping url and method.

Comment: First I wonder that where the sense is in change of controller method.Then it still does no effect. @Rembo

Comment: The problem is resolved.My form is submitted in ajax but I also submit it in "<input type="submit" value="save">"